# Qt: having problems with reading a .txt file

Tags: c++, qt

I begun with Qt a few days ago. However, when I wanted to read a file, however, although the file is open, I can't get a single line from it. The output for qDebug is "The file is open", but the while doesn't do anything (I don't get the "Does it work?" text in my TextArea (a textEdit)).
What am I missing? The file is certainly there, can be opened and has 2 lines.

```
    QFile file("savefile.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug()<<"The file is not open.";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"The file is open.";
        QString line;
        QTextStream in(&file);
        while(!in.atEnd())
        {
            line = in.readLine();
            qDebug()<<"Line: "<<line.toLatin1();
            ui->TextArea->setText("Does it work?");
        }
        file.close();
    }
```

So, what am I missing from this?
I tried to do this accordingly to the Qt Getting Started tutorial, but didn't create the dialog ([Link to the page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html), scroll down to "Opening files"). 
Thank you for any help in advance!

**EDIT 1:** As the file has 2 lines (exactly "Asd." and "asd."), I've replaced the while with a `for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)`. QDebug now tells me twice:

```
Line:  ""
Line:  ""
```

I assume that there's something with the `while(!in.atEnd())` .

**EDIT2:** Replaced the cycle and `in.readLine()` to `ui->TextArea->setText(in.readAll().toLatin1());`. The results are still the same (and if I use `ui->TextArea->setText("Hey!");`, it works.

Comment: Does it work if you hard-code the full path to this, or any, file?  What I'm getting at is perhaps your program's "current directory" is set to something other than where your file is.

Comment: Put the file directly to C:\savefile.txt. The result is the same. From the if(!file.open()), I gather that the file is recognised and opened.

Comment: Make sure you did not use `"C:\savefile.txt"` as a string literal. Remember with c++ you need to escape \ so use `"C:\\savefile.txt"` or `"C:/savefile.txt"` instead of `"C:\savefile.txt"` in your c++ code. Although the compiler should warn you of this a lot of beginners will ignore warnings.

Comment: @drescherjm I checked it. I used "C:/savefile.txt".

Comment: `file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)`

Comment: @ddriver added the piece, still doesn't work. Could you explain why do you need the second piece (QUIDevice::text)?

Comment: Try to print output of `in.readAll()` or `file.readAll()`  instead of reading line by line.

Comment: @KvB - from the doc "When reading, the end-of-line terminators are translated to '\n'. When writing, the end-of-line terminators are translated to the local encoding, for example '\r\n' for Win32"

Comment: I tried using `in.readAll()` instead of `in.readLine()`. QDebug got the same results, textArea is still empty.

Comment: Have you looked at the file with a text editor? To me this sounds like the file is empty.

Comment: Change the filename to something random, like `QFile file("dwofgzosebzvsuilz")`. If the program then reports "The file is not open.", you either have an empty savefile.txt _or_ an additional savefile.txt in another directory.

Comment: ***additional savefile.txt in another directory.*** I was going to add that part but in the comments the OP said they used `"C:/savefile.txt"` as the filename. Although it is unclear if this change was reverted in the code.

Comment: either something is wrong with your file or you are just making an inappropriate and lame joke...

Comment: I reinstalled Qt and it seems to be working now. I'll try to make it fail again to see where the problem was - it seems that changing the name did something too. We'll see.
@ddriver, I wasn't joking. I started learning C++ a few months ago and now I need a UI. I want to "migrate" one of my old programs, giving it a UI, that's why I needed the file reading. No, I wasn't joking, again.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped! I learned quite a few things thanks to you. Hopefully the answer is correct. It was unforeseeable, I cannot guess why could removing Qt and getting it again fix this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been fixed the following way:

**1. Reinstalled Qt.**

I used the Qt Maintenance tool to remove the software from my PC, then downloaded it again. Perhaps some files were missing.

**2. Possible reason for files not opening: wrong folder**

As I've named my project RPG (the project file is RPG.pro), I put the files into the folder RPG and not into the other folder in the same directory, build_RPG_desktop[...], which contains the ui_mainwindow header file (I didn't change the default name from mainwindow). A file "Data.txt" in the build_RPG[...] folder could be read successfully after reinstalling Qt with the following code:

```
QString fileName = "Data.txt";
if (!fileName.isEmpty())
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug()<<"Error. File not found";
        return;
    }
    QTextStream in(&file);
    ui->TextArea->setText(in.readAll());
    file.close();
}
```

Note: I modified my TextEdit field and set its name to TextArea. The `ui->TextArea->setText()` sets the textEdit field's content.